# Как запустить из python внешний файл python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Каким образом можно вызвать выполнение другой программы python (из файла .py) во время выполнения текущей?

Comment: import os os.open()

Comment: пишет open() missing required argument 'flags' (pos 2)

Comment: А добавить недостающий аргумент что мешает?

Answer (score 3):

Можно еще вот так

```
 import os
 os.system('python путь_к_файлу.py')
```

Answer (score 1):

Наверное вам нужно это:

```
import os
os.startfile(r'указывайте здесь путь к файлу')  
#пример os.startfile(r'C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe')
```

Лучше вместе с меткой python 3.x указывайте метку python

Answer (score 1):

`os.startfile('<Путь>')`
или
`os.system('"Каталог1"\"Каталог2"\"Нужный файл"')`

Но если вторая программа -- тоже **.py** файл, то есть ограничения. Это будет работать, только если в системе установлена ассоциация: запускать **.py** файлы с помощью интерепретатора, а не открывать их в каком-нибудь текстовом редакторе.

Лучше будет, если ты скомпилируешь **.py** файл в **.exe** с помощью *pyinstaller* (у новичков могут возникнуть трудности при использовании) или *cxfreeze* (очень удобное управление, но проблемы с тем, чтобы найти этот инструмент и установить). и запустишь уже скомпилированный файл.

**PS:** компиляция приложений, использующих tkinter, полна нюансов (какие библиотеки положить с .exe - фалом, что установить, прописать и т.п.)